# Android Out of memory (many bitmaps)

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I am working on game, where player will fly in sky and player will avoid many enemies.
But on SGS3 I have "Out of memory 720016 - byte allocation.
I have so many bitmaps and i use this code:

```
  BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        bfOptions.inDither=false;                     
        bfOptions.inPurgeable=true;
        bfOptions.inInputShareable=true;
        bfOptions.inTempStorage=new byte[16 * 1024];
```

and I decode many bitmaps with this code

```
amunicja2_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bron2take,bfOptions);
amunicja2_bitmap_full =  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(amunicja2_bitmap, width_amunicja2,  height_amunicja2, false);
```

I have 30 bitmaps like that.
My game is still small (1,25MB but there is a OUT OF MEMORY ERROR) What I can do?

Comment: On which version of Android are you getting the exception?

Comment: Android 4.1.2 on Samsung Galaxy S3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Its a known bug, its not because of large files.
>
> Bitmap is stored in native heap, but it will get garbage collected
>   automatically, calling recycle() or by other process by making
>   weakreference or softreference To fix OutOfMemory you should do
>   something like this:

```
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,bitmapWidth,bitmapHeight);

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

> For example, an image with resolution 2048x1536 that is decoded with
>   an inSampleSize of 4 produces a bitmap of approximately 512x384

[loading images efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: I think that you didn't noticed, that I alredy use "inSampleSize"
amunicja2_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bron2take,bfOptions); ((bfOptions = BitmapFactory.Options();))

Comment: Yes but you set it to 1 (the default) so it doesn't downscale.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my answer here.It will be useful to handle your bitmap efficiently.

[How to make application more responsive which uses several bitmaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627849/how-to-make-application-more-responsive-which-uses-several-bitmaps/20628082#20628082)